# jquery autocomplete for keypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, keypress, jquery-autocomplete

I create comment box like a facebook comment box. I have to do like this in textarea box type @ sign and after I type letter then detect this letter or letters and popup friend list.

```
$("textarea#event_message").autocomplete("friendsAutoComplete");
```

this method used for autocomplete that works fine. but want this method fire after type @ sign.

I tried this way

```
$('textarea#event_message').keypress(function(event) {
      if(event.which == 64) {
            $('textarea#event_message').autocomplete("friendsAutoComplete");
       }
});
```

and I also tried jquery live method

It doesn't like work.How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what is the string "friendsAutoComplete" you referring?

To fire a search using an initialized `autocomplete` widget, you should call the search method instead.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

So you may try out

```
$('textarea#event_message').keypress(function(event) {
      if(event.which == 64) {
            $('textarea#event_message').autocomplete("search");
       }
});
```